# Image reposition in django admin

Tags: python, django

i succesfully shown image in django admin but now i want to reposition in at the right-top-corner.
so how can i write code for it.
please suggest me 
**Models.py**

```
cust_pic=models.ImageField(_('picture'), upload_to='photos/')


def image_tag(self):

    return u'<img src="%s" width=100 height=120/>' % (self.cust_pic.url)
image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

**admin.py**

class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
# )
list_display = ['cust_first_name',]
readonly_fields = ('image_tag','image_tag_thumb',)
admin.site.register(Account,AccountAdmin,)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you will need to override a template, my guess would be `admin/change_form.html`. Another way would be JavaScript. Also, you could try to make your own widget with some weird styles and/or JS applied to it, but I would try to avoid it.

Comment: what should i write in change_from.html

Comment: how to and where to write code in change_form template to change the position of image which i have uploaded